# Handling generic types extending non-generic base

Tags: c#, generics

For PLC (Programmable Logic Controller) communication I have an abstract class `PlcValueAbstract` and extending generic class `PlcValue<T>`. I have these classes so I can specify what to read (T) but to leave the read implementation up to the class doing PLC communication / interop. I need the ability to read multiple of these at the same time, that's where the `PlcValueAbstract` comes in.

Right now I have a method `ReadMultiple(IDictionary<string, PlcValueAbstract> values)` which will read values from registers (PLC) into the paired `PlcValueAbstract`. To achieve this, I check if the `PlcValueAbstract` is either `PlcValue<int>` or `PlcValue<short>` (will be extended to more types) and handle `byte[]` to `PlcValue<>` conversion (`IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverver.ToInt32(bytesFromLibrary))`). However, now my code becomes cluttered with type checks (and exceptions) for every (different) method invocation which uses type `T` on `PlcValue<T>`.

Unfortunately I can't rely on conversion from `byte[]` to `T` either, because we use different brands of PLC's with different register sizes (or API types) and different endianness, so I can't constrain any of my `PlcValue<T>` code to support `byte[]` only.

I have a gut feeling that I'm overcomplicating the issue and thus having to do split type implementations for every supported generic type, which is really cumbersome. **Is there a solution where I can move all the type mumbo-jumbo to just a few methods?**

On request here's part of the implementation:

**PlcValueAbstract:**

```
public abstract class PlcValueAbstract
{
    internal PlcValueAbstract()
    {
    }

    public abstract Type GetUnderlyingType();
}
```

**PlcValue:**

```
public class PlcValue<T> : PlcValueAbstract
{
    public PlcValue(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override Type GetUnderlyingType()
    {
        return typeof(T);
    }
}
```

**SiemensPlc:**

```
public class SiemensPlc
{
    public void WriteMultiple(IDictionary<string, PlcValueAbstract> data)
    {
        IDictionary<string, byte[]> plcData = data.Select(e => BuildWrite(e.Key, e.Value))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        return library.Write(plcData);
    }

    public void Read(IDictionary<string, PlcValueAbstract> data)
    {
        byte[][] response = library.Read(data.Keys);
        PlcValueAbstract[] values = data.Values.ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
        {
            byte[] res = response[i];
            PlcValueAbstract pv = values[i];

            if (pv is PlcValue<int>)
            {
                PlcValue<int> v = (PlcValue<int>)pv;
                v.Value = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(res, 0));
            }
            else if (pv is PlcValue<short>)
            {
                PlcValue<short> v = (PlcValue<short>)pv;
                v.Value = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(res, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid type");
            }
        }
    }

    private KeyValuePair<string, byte[]> BuildWrite(string address, PlcValueAbstract value)
    {
        byte[] data;
        if (value is PlcValue<int>)
        {
            data = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(((PlcValue<int>)value).Value));
        }
        else if (value is PlcValue<short>)
        {
            data = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(((PlcValue<short>)value).Value));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value type is not supported", "value");
        }

        return new KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>(address, data);
    }
```

The above code is a bit of a simplification, the actual code also handles address specification for the different data types.

Comment: Type checks are usually signs that you should be using subclasses, generics or something else. Given you are using generic subclasses it sounds like your code structure is wrong. Can you post some code to more clearly explain what methods are on what classes, etc. It seems that the `PlcValue<T>` should be handling the conversion but isn't...

Comment: Added a basic sample.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just put an abstract method called "SetValueFromResponse" (or similar) on PlcValueAbstract and then each derived class can override it and use the appropriate bitconverter? So then for any type you just call `v.SetValueFromResponse(res, 0)` (not sure what the parameters are but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes. I will use the same classes for different PLC types (it forms an abstraction layer), some of which transfer data in bytes, some transfer in Int16[] and also the order differs (network order, PLC native order).

Comment: Are those different transfer types not what you are encapsulating in your generic parameter? If so the virtual method can take them into account I'd have thought? I'll add an answer with some sample code of what I'm thinking that should at least work with your example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally spent some time and thought on this issue and came up with a solution. I added an `IntermediateReadResult` abstract class that is passed on to the `PlcValueContainerBase` (`PlcValueAbstract` in the original question), which in turn will pass it to `PlcValueContainer<T>` (`PlcValue<T>` in the original question), which will tell the `IntermediateReadResult` that it wants to perform an `Action` with a value of type `T`. The `IntermediateReadResult` in turn passes this on to some implementation in the implementation class (`MitsubishiIntermediateReadResult` in the example below) that will actually do the value conversion. A similar approach is taking for performing the writes. There is some small discrepancy between reads and writes in that for a read of multiple data objects I build one `IntermediateReadResult` for every data container, while for writes I have only one `IntermediateWriteData`. This is not clearly visible from the small example below, but can be figured because only the type is passed (as generic argument) onto the `Apply<TValue>` method.

The effect of the explained structure is that now I can have the following set of implementation classes for a PLC type to implement data reading and writing using `PlcValueContainer`s:

- `BrandDataConverter`
- `BrandIntermediateReadResult`
- `BrandIntermediateWriteData`
- `BrandPlc`

There might be additional classes necessary depending on the PLC supplier's API, but those are always required of course. All the Brand classes live in their own `BrandPlc` assembly so I don't create dependencies on all PLC brands if I need only one (or two). I also have some wrapping code and an abstract PLC class to hide internal API from consumer classes (I don't want the consumers to apply some `CustomIntermediateReadResult` by accident), but other than that the following code example covers most of what is required:

```
public abstract class PlcValueContainerBase
{
    ...

    internal abstract void ApplyReadResult(IntermediateReadResult intermediateReadResult);

    internal abstract void ContributeWrite(IntermediateWriteData intermediateWriteData);

    ...
}

public class PlcValueContainer<TValue> : PlcValueContainerBase
{
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    internal override void ApplyReadResult(IntermediateReadResult intermediateReadResult)
    {
        intermediateReadResult.Apply<TValue>(value => Value = value);
    }

    internal override void ContributeWrite(IntermediateWriteData intermediateWriteData)
    {
        intermediateWriteData.Append(Address, Value, Length);
    }
}

public abstract class IntermediateReadResult
{
    protected internal abstract void Apply<TValue>(Action<TValue> valueAction);
}

class MitsubishiIntermediateReadResult : IntermediateReadResult
{
    private readonly short[] data;

    public MitsubishiIntermediateReadResult(short[] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    protected override void Apply<TValue>(Action<TValue> valueAction)
    {
        valueAction(MitsubishiDataConverter.ConvertFromPlc<TValue>(data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My thinking is that something like this should work:

```
public abstract class PlcValueAbstract
{
    internal PlcValueAbstract()
    {
    }

    public abstract Type GetUnderlyingType();
    public abstract SetValue(byte[] bytes);
}


public class PlcValueInt : PlcValue<int>
{
    public override SetValue(byte[] bytes)
    {
        Value = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0));
    }
}
```

I've made the generic class abstract (not shown) and then there is a setValue method on the base abstract class that takes a byte array and its job is to set the value.

You then derive your concrete classes from this, one for each type you need, and that just needs to implement the one method to parse your result into the value.

Then your problem code will just look like:

for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
   {
       byte[] res = response[i];
       PlcValueAbstract pv = values[i];

```
    pv.SetValue(res);
```

}

This code has not been tested or compiled but the principles should be sound, even if it needs a bit of tweaking to get it working.

You are essentially shuffling your type check code around, removing the need for checking what the type is in favour of having a class declaration for each of your datatypes.

The main reason this works is because the method signature for `SetValue` doesn't need to know what the underlying type is, it just needs to take a certain input and then does whatever it wants internally so it can easily be called without knowing anything more.

Comment: Main issue is I don't always have `byte[]` data and this is single direction only. I'm thinking maybe a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, byte[]>>` can help me, but still feels ugly.

Comment: Your read class implied that your response that you were reading was always going to be a byte array. Similarly your write function seemed to always return bytes. Sadly I'm not familiar with the domain you are working in so features that might be obvious to you are unknown to me. :)

Comment: Yes, I tried to lay it out as well as I could in my question. We also use Mitsubishi PLC's, the library used for that returns everything in Int16[] and the byte ordering there differs from the Siemens library / PLC.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though what you need may be to define an `IPlcValue` interface which contains members to find an item's underlying type, as well as to convert that type to or from a series of bytes [the routine to convert from a series of bytes could be written to use a stream, or could accept an array of bytes along the length of the valid portion of the array and a `nextOffset` value, the latter being passed as a `ref int`].  In addition to that, one should define an `IPlcValue<T>` interface which contains a `Value` member of type `T`.  Once one has done those things, one could define class(es) `PlcIntegerMsbFirst` and/or `PlcIntegerLsbFirst` which would implement `IPlcValue<int>`, a PlcString which implements `IPlcValue<String>` [if any PLCs use strings], etc.  Code which has a collection of IPlcValue items could convert them all to or from a sequence of bytes without having to know about their underlying types; code which knows that something should be a number could access it as `IPlcValue<int>` without having to know whether it was stored MSB-first or LSB-first, etc.

Comment: Parts are similar to the code I have (though I have an abstract class with internal constructor so I can control what classes extend it), but other parts would limit it to byte[] only, which wouldn't work well. Also the PlcIntegerMsbFirst and Lsb variant are **not** what I want, it would prevent derived classes that map data to, for instance, an enum.

Comment: If you want something that maps to MyEnum, then you should define a class which inherits `IPlcValue<MyEnum>`.  If proper handling of type MyEnum is going to need type-specific logic, then there should be a class which encapsualtes that logic.  My point with the MSB/LSBfirst classes was to make clear that if there are multiple PLC record formats which are used to store the same underlying data type, one may without difficulty accommodate that.

Comment: The PLC doesn't know about enums, so I'm not sure about the IPlcValue<MyEnum>. Then again, it would be stored as the enum's UnderlyingType which would make the conversion logic equal to IPlcValue<int> or IPlcValue<short>. The issue with separate LSB/MSB classes is that I would need different abstraction layers for different PLC types, or another abstraction layer on top.

Comment: @mycroes: I would expect that each PLC type would define a collection of objects which implement IPlcValue.  A PLC which stores its values MSB first would include instances of the MSB-first class; one which stores them LSB-first would use instances of the LSB-first class.  A client would see things of type `IPlcValue<int>`, but wouldn't know nor care whether they represented MSb-first or LSb-first transpators.

Comment: The issue is the client will actually provide PlcValue<T>, because the client knows the data it wants. Otherwise I would have a read method that returns IPlcValue and the client would have to do typechecks. Adding the fact that it's not only MSB/LSB differences, but also native type differences (byte[] vs Int16[]), this would mean implementing a class for every datatype for every PLC, which is not really what I'm after.